# Can we have an "off topic because..." option for things that smell like programming problems, but actually are issues with the user's setup?

Tags: discussion

I'm frustrated by the lack of a standard place to put questions that smell like programming problems to the user asking, but actually aren't related to the programming at all.

Two examples:

- "Why isn't PHP sending my mail?  Here is my form and my code etc etc etc but it never works."  ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438850/php-mail-not-send-emails))
- "What's wrong with this query?  I have this code and my query and I execute it and it says is 'Unable to connect to mysql database'.  What's wrong with my query?"  ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023326/unable-to-connect-to-the-database-mysql-using-php))

These are not problems with the user's code but with something wrong in their environment in the MySQL case, or any of a huge number of problems in the mail delivery case.  These questions always turn into SO helpers trying to debug system environments at a distance, which doesn't feel like what SO should be used for.

These are problems that are reproducible by the user, but are specific to their environments.

Comment: "Can no longer be reproduced or simple typographic error"?

Comment: If they are mysql server issues, why not point them to ServerFault? It _might_ be on-topic there depending on the scope of the question.

Comment: The intent of the new "minimal example" close reason seems to fit here. The user has a specific problem and did not include enough information to diagnose and reproduce it; but the information needed is not his code but configuration or log files etc. Maybe the close reason could be reworded to include this type of questions, e.g. something like "Questions seeking troubleshooting help must include [...] the minimal information neccessary to reproduce the problem. In case of code, provide a minimal example, otherwise post the relevant excerpts of logs and configuration files".

Comment: Agreed: it is not off-topic by virtue of being an "issue with the user's setup". Configuration of environment (if what they're trying and failing to run is still their own custom code) is definitely part of programming, or the "'Works on My Machine' Certification Program" joke wouldn't make sense. It *is* definitely off-topic by virtue of them not providing enough information, though.

Comment: If we did this, you may as well burninate both the [tag:Spring] and [tag:Hibernate] tags to begin with. 90% of the questions posted there can be put down to configuration problems. I agree it may be a problem on under a pure programming language tag, but highly inappropriate under a framework tag where configuration plays a big part of the solution.

Answer (score 5):

There is a specific close reason for problems:

> caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced

That applies to these types of questions, where you cannot reproduce the problem.

You can also use "unclear" for questions that do not contain sufficient information in the question to be answerable.

Comment: But the problem *can* be reproduced by the user.  It's just that the problem is not a programming one.

Comment: @Andy, I doubt the close reason was ever intended to mean that the OP is the one who can't reproduce it, or at least it certainly isn't exclusively that

Comment: @AndyLester Then use unclear, as the question does not contain enough information to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The questions you seem to be describing sound like they actually **are** on topic.

If a user has a question about why **a program they wrote** doesn't work, and s/he's given an SSCCE, and clearly explained the problem, and has done all the things we expect of people asking about a bug in their code, then their question is on topic regardless of what the answer ends up being.

Remember, you close **questions** as off topic.  not answers.

Comment: The whole point here is that the questions *don't* contain enough information to reproduce the problem.  When someone posts a query and the query works just fine, and there is an environmental problem, the question isn't answerable, unless the question includes enough information to diagnose what that environmental problem is (which wasn't the case for either example given).

Comment: @Servy But the problem _can_ be reproduced by the user. It's just that the problem is not a programming one.

Comment: But the problems cannot be reproduced by *us*.  The questions do not contain enough information to be answerable.  If they are also off topic as not being programming questions, then by all means, close them for that reason too, if you prefer.  When a question has multiple problems you're free to just choose one.  Personally, when I can't reproduce a problem, it's hard to say whether the actual problem is in fact code related or not, since you can't know where the problem lies, but that's my preference.  If you feel that you can justify closing the question as offtopic, that's fine.

Comment: @servy I'm just saying, is that judging from the things that the OP has said, it appears that this question is **really** about programming questions about non-programming problems rather than reproducibility.

Comment: And I'm saying that rather than trying to close the question about an unreproducable problem as offtopic for not being programming related, simply because you suspect that the problem you don't have enough information to diagnose might not be programming related, you should instead close it for not having enough information.  If it is answerable and contains enough information to make it conclusively clear that it's not a programming question, then there should be no debate in closing the question as offtoipc.

Comment: @Servy I looked at the question again, and It is clearly about questions related to programming that are not caused by programming problems.  "_unreproducable problems_" and "_not even programming **related** problems_" don't appear to be at the core of this question.  Those are things that you appear to have projected onto the question

Comment: If the question contains enough information to conclusively say that it is demonstrably not programming related, then sure, close it as offtopic for not being a programming problem, as I've said before.  You are correct that I'm the one making the assertion that the questions here don't contain enough information to be answerable, and that's my interpretation of why the OP feels it's not a programming problem, I don't refute that it's a fallible assumption.